# Angular Route JS

Tags: angularjs

```
 .when('/security/login', {
          templateUrl: '/login/view',
          controller: 'cloudtool,
          resolve: {
              stmt: function(){
                  return "vicky";
              }
          }
```

//Controller

```
angular.module('cloudtool')
    .controller('cloudtool', ['$scope',
        function ($scope,stmt) {
            console.log(stmt);
```

I want "vicky" to get as output in console. this results in undefined. How can i overcome this?

Comment: Is it a typo, or are you really missing the closing apostrophe on your `controller:` line? Also, you'll need to add `'stmt'` to your injection array.

Comment: You're injecting the scope but you're not injecting the resolved function, change your code to `['$scope','stmt',`

Comment: apostrophe on my controller: line is a typo.. but when i inject the resolved function in the array it gives me an error i.e:Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: stmtProvider <- stmt <- cloudtool

Comment: Does another route use this controller?

Comment: yes one more route

Comment: Does that have the resolve in as well?

Comment: it got solved.. thank you @George Lee